# Access data members of another class in overloading operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, private-members

I have this operator

```
Mtx Mtx::operator*(const Vtr &rhs) const
{
Mtx Q(nrows, ncols, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
        Q.ets[i][j] = 0.0;

        for (int k = 0; k < rhs.length; ++k) {
            Q.ets[i][j] += ets[i][k] * rhs.ets[k];
        }
    }
  }
return Q;
}
```

I call this operator by `M3 = M1 * V1`, I receive compiler errors because `length` and `ets[k]` in the third loop are private members of class `Vtr`. How can I access them?

Answer (score 4):

Let `Mtx` be a friend of `Vtr`.

```
 class Vtr {
     friend class Mtx;
     //...
 };
```

Or let the `Mtx::operator*` method be a friend.

```
 class Vtr {
     friend Mtx Mtx::operator*(const Vtr &) const;
     //...
 };
```

Either of these changes will let your current implementation work without any further changes.

Answer (score 4):

Either make `Mtx` a friend of `Vtr` or provide public assess to the data, for example

```
class Vtx {
 public:
  const SomeType& operator[](unsigned int i) const { return ets[i]; }

};
```

This actually decouples the data access from the underlying implementation, since the operator can be implemented in different ways.

On the other hand, it provides a direct access to the underlying representation, so it adds the constraint that you cannot change the implementation in a way that changes the mapping between a given index and a given element.

Comment: I made it friend, and it worked. But the above code didn't work. Is there any thing hidden?

Comment: The accessor needs to be public. The OP's code needs to change to use `[]` directly on `rhs`. Also, need a `length` accesssor.

Comment: @JackintheBox could it be the public issue? Otherwise, there isn't anything (purposefully) hidden

Answer (score 2):

Friend is your answer!!

Either you can make the class a friend or the function.

But I'm not sure if that is the correct logic for you case.

Mostly if you cant access a variable that means you shouldn't access it.

Check if you are doing correctly with access specifiers. And the only way to go about is friend then use 'friend' function or class.

Comment: +1 for both points : *"Either you can make **the class** a friend or **the function**"*